# (node) How do I get random values when an api is hit with a get request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I am trying to get a random word when the endpoint '/randomword' is hit.
I used Math.random to get a random number between the array index numbers- and try to get a random word by accessing an element with a random index. This code does give me a random word at first but it doesn't change with each get request.

I wrote this and it does return a random word but it doesn't change with each get request.

```
   rInt = getRandomInt(2)

   function getRandomInt(max) {return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);}

    wordList  = [
    {"word": "abase",
     "type": "verb",
     "meaning": "lower in position; degrade"},

     {"word": "abbess",
      "type": "verb", 
       "meaning": "lady superior of a nunnery"},
  
     {"word": "abbot", 
      "type": "noun",
      "meaning": "head of monks"}
    ]

    randomWord = wordList[rInt];//console.log(randomWord);

    app.get('/randomword', function (req, res) {res.status(200).send(randomword)})
```

Comment: You need to generate the random number upon each individual request. As it is, you get a single random number just once.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks- it seems to be super obvious- don't know how I missed that. :)